# REDUX: How can I delete related item from my array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a project in React using Redux. I am trying to delete an item. However, it added an array to my array. How can I delete it? Here is my code:

```
import ActionTypes from "../constants/ActionTypes";

const initialState = {
  myCities: [],
  aCity: {},
  getCityById: {},
};

export const WeatherReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.GETBY_CITYNAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        aCity: payload,
        myCities: [...state.myCities, payload],
      };
    case ActionTypes.GETCITYBYID:
      return {
        ...state,
        getCityById: payload,
        myCities: [], //first I tried to it empty, not works at all and I also tried without it
        myCities: [ 
          ...state.myCities,
          initialState.myCities.filter((item) => item.id !== payload.id), //Then I tried to find related item, choose it and add all objects to my array without related item
        ],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I also added my delete stuff:

```
const HandleDelete = (cityId) => {
  dispatch(GetCityById(cityId, apiKEY));
};
```

Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

The [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method already returns a new array, so there is no need to put it inside of another array here

```
myCities: [ 
  ...state.myCities,
  initialState.myCities.filter((item) => item.id !== payload.id)
],
```

The above creates a new array `[]`, and then puts all the elements in `state.myCities` into that new array using the [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Then, it adds a new element, which is the filtered array of `initialState.myCities.filter()`. Instead, as `.filter()` returns an array only containing the items your callback returned `true` for, you can directly use that array as the new value for `myCities:`

```
myCities: initialState.myCities.filter((item) => item.id !== payload.id)
```

Comment: I tried but it makes my array empty.

Comment: @CerenKeklik Try and console log the values of item.id and payload.id in the filter callback and see if they're what you expect them to be and if they're ever equal to each other (the type must also be the same): `.filter((item) => {console.log(item.id, payload.id); return item.id !== payload.id})`

Comment: it prints nothing :/

Comment: Hm, oh right, initialState.myCities is an empty array, maybe you want to use: state.myCities.filter... instead

Comment: I dont understand. initialState.myCities is empty at first as you said. However, I first fill it. I add new cities. Then I try to delete an item from this array. But, it deletes all items in myCities

Comment: The array in initialState object is never modified/touched. Instead, you’re creating an new object with all the properties from initialState, and then setting the myCities property in the new state object to a new array of values. When doing this, the initialState object’s myCities array doesn’t change, so initialState.myCities will still be an empty array. If you need to keep the original cities array, you can instead create a new property on your state object and such as filteredCities (that way of you need to filter the original myCities array you can as you won’t be overwriting it)